# angularfire2 firestore document snapshotChanges action type

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Why in the results of

```
this.afs.doc(`items/${item}`).snapshotChanges()
```

unlike what the docs says, I have the result of type = 'value' **and not**  added | modified | removed, thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get added, modified, and removed events you'll want to observe `stateChanges`. `snapshotChanges` and `valueChanges` scan over these events and coalesce the value, for simplicity.

Documents however, only ever emit a `value` and don't have a `stateChanges` observable. See the docs here, [Documents in AngularFirestore](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#snapshotchanges).

Comment: thanks, but when I add, or change a value on doc, o remove it I have always this result in console
{payload: DocumentSnapshot, type: "value"}

Comment: Oh sorry, I read as collection... let me look at this and see if It's behaving correctly. It may not be. Can you open a bug on Github?

Comment: clarified the answer, right now docs only emit value; I'd suggest opening a ticket on Github if you want to see adds, updates, and deletes

Comment: I have the same issue.